# Javascript Working in FF + IE9 but not IE8

Tags: javascript

As the title says, my code works in the latest Firefox and IE9 but not IE8. Could anyone tell me why? Or perhaps give me another solution to hiding/showing a div based on a selected element. Thanks

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
    /* Hide drop down if certain option selected */
    function hideField(field_id){
        var field = document.getElementById(field_id);
        field.style.display = "none";
    }
    /* Show drop down if certain option selected */
    function showField(field_id){
        var field = document.getElementById(field_id);
        if(field.style.display = "none"){
            field.style.display = "block";
        }
    }
-->
</script>


                    <select name="subject" id="subject" >
                        <option value="unselected">Please Select...</option>
                        <option value="Advertising" onclick="hideField('browserRow'),hideField('versionRow')">Advertising</option>
                        <option value="Complaint" onclick="hideField('browserRow'),hideField('versionRow')">Complaint</option>
                        <option value="Content Issue" onclick="hideField('browserRow'),hideField('versionRow')">Content/Information</option>
                        <option value="Website Error" onclick="showField('browserRow'),showField('versionRow')">Website Bug/Error</option>
                        <option value="Website Feedback" onclick="hideField('browserRow'),hideField('versionRow')">Website Feedback</option>
                        <option value="Other" onclick="hideField('browserRow'),hideField('versionRow')">Other</option>
                    </select>

            <div class="row" id="browserRow">
                <label>Your Browser: <font color="#FF0000">*</font></label>
                <select name="browser" id="browser">
                    <option value="unselected">Please Select...</option>
                    <option value="Android">Android</option>
                    <option value="Google Chrome">Google Chrome</option>
                    <option value="Mozilla Firefox">Mozilla Firefox</option>
                    <option value="Internet Explorer">Internet Explorer</option>
                    <option value="Safari">Safari</option>
                    <option value="Opera">Opera</option>
                    <option value="Other">Other</option>
                </select>
             </div>

            <div class="row" id="versionRow">
                <label>Browser Version: <font color="#FF0000">*</font></label>
                <input type="text" name="version" value="<?php echo $session->userinfo['version']; ?>" maxlength="10" id="bVersion">
                <span class="error"><?php echo $form->error("version"); ?></span>
                <script language="javascript">
                    var number = document.getElementById('version');
                    selectItemByValue(number, '<?php echo $form->value('version'); ?>');
                </script>
            </div>
```

Comment: What is the problem? What happens and what you expect to happen? Please provide a useful error description and not just *"it does not work"*.

Comment: Are you testing IE8 on another machine? Does that machine have JavaScript enabled?

Comment: Please define "doesn't work". What happens or doesn't happen? What errors do you get?

Comment: The post is self explanatory Felix. The give away is in "Or perhaps give me another solution to hiding/showing a div based on a selected element."

Comment: I am testing IE8 on the same machine via F12 view mode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**IE** does not support `onclick` for `<option>`.

The workaround is to use `onchange` on `<select>`.

See [IE capture option element onclick](http://matthom.com/archive/2006/08/08/ie-capture-option-element-onclick) for a detailed explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Try using semicolon instead of comma in here:

```
onclick="hideField('browserRow');hideField('versionRow')"
```

Comment: +1 Good catch. That could do it. Weird that IE9 and FF would accept comma-delmited method calls, though...

Answer (score 0):

The one big problem you have here is in your `showField` function:

```
if(field.style.display = "none")
```

This line of code is incorrect. You have used a single equal in the `if()` rather than a double-equal, so it will set the value of the display propery rather than checking what the value is.

This isn't the cause of your IE8 problem, but it is a serious error which needs to be pointed out. (although by pure luck it probably wouldn't have caused any issues for you in this case)

Comment: My if statement wasnt actually required anyway so i just removed it. Still no joy with IE8 though.